# Specifying size on <html> element and showing page in A4 paper format

Tags: html, css

I am trying to develop document in HTML, which I want to use in A4 paper format.

So I specify `width` and `height` on `body` element, but then `footer` overflows (border is specified on `body` element):

[image]

While specifying size on `<html>` element works as below:

[image]

I thought that it should be somehow equivalent, because `body` is container for all visible components in HTML. But it isn't.

But even specifying size on `<html>` element, the page isn't shown in A4 format.

1. Is showing page as A4 page opossible?
2. Why size on `<html>` and `<body>` works different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some similiar challenges recently when designing a print stylesheet for my resume :-)

Yes, it is possible. Although you might need to tinker a bit before it works.
(I worked with the Print preview of my web browser for now - but the resulting PDF will be inaccessible and loose all semantics).

Some resources to get you started:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/

Regarding your second question: I'd go with a `<div class="wrapper"></div>` as only child of `<body>` and use a reset stylesheet. I met too many quirks otherwise.

If you want to learn more, Geoff Graham [wrote about it a couple years ago](https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/).